# How to load Category image in top menu?

Tags: category, magento2.3, topmenu, category-image

I have loaded the category and sub-category, now I need to load image as well but I'm not sure how to do that.

Below is the code I have used:

**In block file:**

```
public function getStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true)
    {
        return $this->_categoryHelper->getStoreCategories($sorted , $asCollection, $toLoad);
    }

    public function getCategoryById($categoryId) 
    {
        return $this->_categoryRepository->get($categoryId);

    }
```

**In phtm file:**

```
<header class="headers">
  <div class="header-inrs">
    <div class="menu-container">
      <div class="menus contenedor-menu">
        <ul class="clearfix backcolor designmenu">
          <div class="totalmobilelog">
            <div class="lo">
              <a href="" ><b class="clsml"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>Login</b></a>
            </div>
            <div class="si">
              <a href="" ><b class="clsml"><i class="fa fa-registered" aria-hidden="true"></i>Sign Up</b></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <?php
          $categories = $block->getStoreCategories();
          foreach ($categories as $category):

          ?>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $category->getRequestPath();?>"><?php echo $category->getName(); ?></a>
          <ul class="subc">
            <?php
            $subCategories = $block->getCategoryById($category->getId());
            foreach ($subCategories->getChildrenCategories() as $subCategory):
            ?>

            <li><a href="<?php echo $subCategory->getRequestPath();?>"><?php echo $subCategory->getName(); ?></a>
          </li>

          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php echo $block->getSubcategories($subCategories); ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</header>
```

Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

To get Category Image url:

```
<?php echo $category->getImageUrl(); ?>
```

And use it in `<img>` tag like

```
<img src="<?php  echo $category->getImageUrl(); ?>" />
```

And get Alternate Image url:

```
echo $category->getImageUrl('category_alternate_image'); 
<img src="<?php  echo $category->getImageUrl('category_alternate_image'); ?>" />
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Thanks. Where do I need to put this code? Is it in phtml, right?

Comment: @Siva Yes in phtml

Comment: I have tried the code <?php echo $category->getImageUrl(); ?> in my phtml file but nothing happens. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Have you put this  `<?php echo $category->getImageUrl(); ?>` in `<img>` tag like I mentioned in my answer? if you did then either you are in wrong phtml or you `category` object is not properly loaded.

Comment: I have put the code as you said and uploaded a category image via admin panel but still the image is not loading in the desired place. Can you please help?